# Grant permission to single class

Tags: java, security, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm working with a security policy on Tomcat 6.  I've successfully granted permissions to my entire webapp, but would like to grant some permissions only to specific classes.  However, when I try this, my doPrivileged block receives an AccessControlException.

Because I've been successful granting to a more general code base, I went back to that codebase, and tested as I added each additional subdirectory.  In this manner, the most specific grant I'm able to make work is:

grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/-" {
    ...
    }

If I add "classes/", as in:

grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/-" {
    ...
    }

then I resume seeing the AccessControlException.  The class I'm trying to allow is located beneath the classes directory.  The webapp was deployed as a .war file, and unpacked by Tomcat.

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm intending to follow the example provided in the catalina.policy provided with Tomcat.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this.  usually permissions are based a per user basis.

Comment: I'm trying to tell the Java SecurityManager to allow certain classes to perform certain actions. (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The finest granularity for assigning permissions using the Java default policy file format is per-code source (i.e., per-JAR or per-class-directory).  As a workaround, you could split each distinctly privileged class into its own JAR in WEB-INF/lib and grant specific permissions to that JAR.

A custom ClassLoader could be made to create unique ProtectionDomains for each defineClass. The ProtectionDomains could either statically grant per-class permissions, or they could create specialized ProtectionDomains to allow a custom Policy to dynamically grant per-class permissions.